"Propagation" of WHERE condition from nested to outer query
I rarely ever write SQL queries for more than just trivial tasks and so I was surprised to see the following behaviour that I'd like to demonstrate in a minimal example.
Table: stamps               Table: users
| ts |                      | name     | lastlogin |
+----+                      +----------+-----------+
| 10 |                      | foo      | 12        |
| 12 |                      | bar      | 12        |
| 18 |                      | bim      | 18        |
| 20 |                      | bam      | 10        | 
| 25 |                      | zoom     | 25        |
+----+                      | dang     | 20        |
                            +----------+-----------+

Query:


SELECT u.lastlogin, u.name FROM stamps s
JOIN users u ON u.lastlogin = s.ts
WHERE s.ts in (
  SELECT si.ts FROM stamps si WHERE si.ts > 10 AND u.name LIKE 'b%'  
)


(Having that name condition on the inner query seems weird, but in the real use case, the inner query is more complex and the condition is needed there for some reasons.)
What I thought would happen:

the inner query would select the timestamps 12 and 18
the outer query would select all users whose last login was at 12 or 18, i. e. foo, bar and bim
in order to have only the users whose name starts with a B, I would have to add a WHERE clause to the outer query

But what actually happens is that the query only returns users bar and bim. Although that was the desired outcome, it was completely unexpected to me, being anything but a DB professional.
Three questions:

Why or how does the condition in the nested query have an effect on the outer query, even though it seems to only filter for a set of timestamps?
Does that effect have a name and is that a behaviour one can count on in all SQL flavours?
What would one do if that effect was not desired, but -- for some reasons -- the condition could not be removed from the nested query?

Edit
As requested in the comments, I try to give a brief description of the task:

Students take an online test containing various questions.
Upon starting the test and on each (automatic or manual) save, a DB entry is created storing the timestamp, the userid, the id of the question and some sequence code. The entry does not contain the id of the test itself. An interaction can touch multiple questions at once, e.g. all of them when the test starts. In that case, multiple entries are created, all with the same time stamp.
Note that the sequence code is not strictly increasing, because it is per question and also depends whether the save was automatic or manual. So the most recent interaction does not necessarily have the greatest sequence code.
For every student belonging to a certain group (e. g. a class), I want to retrieve the timestamp and the sequence code of the last interaction for a given test.
I use a GROUP BY query with MAX(timestamp) and some filtering to get the timestamp of the latest interaction per student, but only for students belonging to the group and only for interactions belonging to the given test.
As I also need the sequence code and as this code is not strictly increasing, I do run a second (outer) query selecting all interactions that happened at a given time.
However, by chance, some other student from another class could possibly have saved a question belonging to another test at the exact same time, so I want the results of the outer query to be filtered accordingly. To my surprise, that already happened.



When the query uses more than one table then add table name to EACH column name (even when it is unique). 2. When the query uses more than one table copy then assign unique alias to EACH table copy. 3. Post the task, not only your attempt to solve it.


Having that name condition on the inner query seems weird, but in the real use case, the inner query is more complex and the condition is needed there for some reasons. Your condition by outer table's column does not correlate with subquery source, so it must be moved out of the subquery. After this you'll understand that the query logic does not match the task.

name? there is no name column in either of the published tables please take a moment to make the data and query consistent.

@Akina Added that. The aliases and table names are there in the original query, I just left them out here to make the example shorter. Will add the task as well.

@P.Salmon Thanks, that was a typo.

When you reference an outer column within a subquery, you're creating what's known as a correlated subquery. This means that "logically" the subquery is separately evaluated for each row in the outer query1.
In this case, when the subquery is being evaluated for rows which have a name not starting with b, the inner query's whole WHERE clause evaluates as false and so the subquery returns no rows. Which then means that the IN condition cannot be true.
This is absolutely standard behaviour.

1How much the inner query needs to be re-evaluated is, as always with SQL, subject to how smart the optimizer can be with the specific conditions it's working with.

Thank you very much for your explanation. So my misconception was mainly to believe that the queries were - similar to maths - executed from the inside to the outside, i. e. first retrieving all timestamps and then feeding those values to the outer query.

BTW I now realise that it is better to filter the students on the outside, thus having the inner query run fewer times rather than filtering as tightly as possible on the timestamps, thinking there would be fewer of them to be checked when running the outer query.

@PhilippImhof - don't spend too long trying to "help" the optimizer. In SQL you tell the system what you want, not how to do it. If you provide two queries that are differently structured but boil down logically to the same requirements, the optimizer should (under normal circumstances) produce the same plan for both of them.
